# How do I run an imported Spring project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've imported a Spring project from Eclipse which runs perfectly. When I go to the run/debug configurations and it asks me to choose the main class I don't know which to choose as there is a lot.

With Eclipse I just right clicked the project and selected Run on server, selected WildFly 10 and it ran on `localhost:8080` but it seems a little more complicated here. How do I run this project?

Comment: Was your Eclipse project successfully imported into IntelliJ? You've had no issues before running it?

Comment: It seemed to be a clean import. I had a few issues with unresolved dependencies but I fixed them by adding them to maven which the eclipse project seemingly didn't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting JBoss. JBoss was renamed to WildFly. Not sure why it's still JBoss in IntelliJ. You can add a server using Run > Edit Configurations > + . Just choose JBoss in the list.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-server-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: Selecting it from where?